# Is 'to' a preposition or conjunction in the sentence?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, conjunctions

> I was preoccupied with getting cute girls to like me.

What is the role of 'to' in this sentence?

Comment: The sentence is not grammatically correct.  I think you probably want something like *I was preoccupied with getting cute girls to like me*.

Comment: You're right. Message was edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is not grammatically correct.

As @stevekeiretsu says in his comment, perhaps the writer meant, "I was preoccupied with getting cute girls to like me" or something similar.

In any case, "to" is not serving as either a preposition or a conjunction in this sentence. It is used to create an infinitive, "to like".

I don't think "to" is ever used as a conjunction. Not in normal, grammatically correct English anyway. If someone can think of an example where it is, I'd be interested in seeing it.

Comment: Maybe it's a subordinate conjunction?

Comment: Not here, here it's making an infinitive. But okay, I guess when "to" is used in the sence of "because", it might act as a subordinate conjunction. Like, "To impress his girlfriend, George destroyed an empire." I guess you'd call "to" a subordinate conjunction there.

Comment: No, that's still a prepositional phrase, just with an inversion.  I think you were originally correct.. I can't think of a situation where "to" is ever used as a conjunction (that would require a complete, separable statement (e.g. subject + verb + ...) following "to")..

Comment: @Foogod You're right, it's a prepositional phrase, not a dependent clause. So I return to my original statement: I can't think of an example where "to" is used as a conjunction.